# PHP - $variable = value1 or value2

Tags: php, operators

```
$val1 = false;
$val2 = 10;

$variable = $val1 || $val2;
```

the code above makes `$variable = true`.

Is there any operator in PHP that would make `$variable` take the value of `$val2`, if `$val1` is false?
I thought `||` would do this, but it only returns true if any of the values are true, or false if both are false...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ternary operator

```
$variable = ($val1) ? $val1 : $val2;
```

or (in PHP 5.3+ )

```
$variable = ($val1) ?: $val2;
```

Comment: You should mention that the second possibility is only available in PHP >= 5.3.

Comment: (+1) I was typing an answer, then I saw yours show up. I wasn't aware of the second syntax!

Comment: @Felix, thats what I wanted to do originally, and the reason I put the longer version first :) Fixed, cheers.

Comment: tx. can this also check more than 2 values? like $var = $a || $b || c ... ?

Comment: @Alex: affraid not, at this time.

Answer (score 3):

The operator `||` does a logical or, that's why you only get true or false back.

You might want to use PHP [ternary](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator:

```
$variable = $val1? "default value" : $val2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also absue operator precedence:

```
$variable = $value1  or  $variable = "value2";
```

`or` is weaker than `=`. It gets more readable if you add extra spaces. But it's more or less a workaround for the lack of ?: in PHP<5.3.

Comment: interesting, this one works with multiple values like `$var = $a   or $var = $b   or ....`